# Any Way to Read JAAS Configuration File from Memory

Tags: java, security, authentication, jaas

We use JAAS in a heavily loaded web server. The configuration file is loaded from a file,

```
  System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "/config/jaas.config");
```

During profiling, we noticed that the configuration is loaded from file for every login attempt. This is an I/O operation we try to avoid. Is there anyway to store the JAAS configuration in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement your own [Configuration](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/security/auth/login/Configuration.html). The javadoc says:

> The default Configuration
>   implementation can be changed by
>   setting the value of the
>   "login.configuration.provider"
>   security property (in the Java
>   security properties file) to the fully
>   qualified name of the desired
>   Configuration implementation class.

The default implementation [com.sun.security.auth.login.ConfigFile (source)](http://www.javadocexamples.com/com/sun/security/auth/login/com.sun.security.auth.login.ConfigFile-source.html) appears to load the file each time the class is instantiated. You could cache the contents. No comment on the security aspects either way.

Answer (score 8):

Following code snippet connects to a PostgreSQL database (using pgjdbc and HikariCP) with an in-memory JAAS configuration, that is, no `Configuration` files are required:

```java
package com.vlkan.kerberos.auth;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;
import javax.security.auth.login.Configuration;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;

public enum Main {

    private static final String JAAS_CONFIG_NAME = "pgjdbc";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, SQLException {

        String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://host/dbname";
        String jdbcDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pass";

        Configuration jaasConfig = createJaasConfig();
        Configuration.setConfiguration(jaasConfig);

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = createHikariConfig(jdbcUrl, jdbcDriver, username, password);
        HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
        try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT 1")) {
                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    boolean next = resultSet.next();
                    checkArgument(next, "no results");
                    int result = resultSet.getInt(1);
                    checkArgument(result == 1, "expecting: 1, found: %s", result);
                    System.out.println("ok");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static HikariConfig createHikariConfig(String jdbcUrl, String jdbcDriver, String username, String password) {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDriverClassName(jdbcDriver);
        config.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        config.setUsername(username);
        config.setPassword(password);
        fixKerberosProperties(config, username, password);
        return config;
    }

    private static void fixKerberosProperties(HikariConfig config, String username, String password) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("user", username);
        properties.setProperty("password", password);
        properties.setProperty("JAASConfigName", JAAS_CONFIG_NAME);
        config.setDataSourceProperties(properties);
    }

    private static Configuration createJaasConfig() {

        // Create entry options.
        Map<String, Object> options = ImmutableMap.of(
                "useFirstPass", "false",    // Do *not* use javax.security.auth.login.{name,password} from shared state.
                "debug", "true"             // Output debug (including plain text username and password!) messages.
        );

        // Create entries.
        AppConfigurationEntry[] entries = {
                new AppConfigurationEntry(
                        "com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule",
                        AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED,
                        options)
        };

        // Create configuration.
        return new Configuration() {
            @Override
            public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name) {
                checkArgument(JAAS_CONFIG_NAME.equals(name));
                return entries;
            }
        };

    }

}
```

Comment: Great answer, helped me a lot! Wouldn't recommend using the private class `Krb5LoginModule` though as you would need to include `rt.jar` in your project's libraries.